# Dreamweaver and Photoshop on Linux Mint

Tags: adobe-photoshop, linux-mint, wine, dreamweaver

I have a simple question.

Is it legal to use Dreamweaver and Photoshop (both bought legally) on linux using Wine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's nothing requiring you to use them on Windows.

Comment: Yes, but is Wine absolutely legal (since I'm planning on using this at a company)?

Comment: Yes, it would only be illegal if it contained actual Windows components - which it doesn't. Wine is just a compatibility layer. Wine dates back to 1993, if it were going to be in any legal trouble - it would have done so already. Additionally many high profile software publishers use Wine(lib) to provide Linux versions of their software.